# How would I retrieve the correct value of a subcategory?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

Initially, a JComboBox is populated with some strings values
like "Textures", "Products" etc
And they are attributed with a character
like 'T', 'P' so that the table would look like this

```
CREATE TABLE Category (  
  CategoryID INTEGER  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
                (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)  ,
  CategoryCode VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
  CategoryName VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL


);

INSERT INTO Category (CategoryCode, CategoryName) VALUES('T','Textures');
INSERT INTO Category (CategoryCode, CategoryName) VALUES('D','Diamonds');
INSERT INTO Category (CategoryCode, CategoryName) VALUES('P','Products');
```

When they are retrieved from a JComboBox, I do something like this

```
cbSCategory.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                // sid = cbSCategory.getSelectedIndex();
                try {
                    setProductCol();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
                    Logger.getLogger(ProductPanel2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        });
```

Now I can't have the index and the character representation of the attribute
How do I retrieve the value of the attribute correctly?
Thanks
Jack

Comment: ((JComboBox) e.getSource()).getSelectedItem() returns the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a java class to represent Category and keep in the JComboBox

```
public class Category {
    int id;
    String code;
    String name;
}
```

Override toString() method to return the 'name' field and place list of the Category objects in the JComboBox.

On selection you can get selected item and read `id` or `code`.

Comment: Hi, what if I have to return a char instead of a string for toString()? Notice a char is not a string

Comment: you can use myCharVariable+""